# Nlp Manager for chatbot creation in backend

Tags: node.js, express, nlp, chatbot, router

I'm trying to create an api endpoint using(Node.js and Express) for a chatbot and use in react.
I've written the code but whenever i'm hitting the request in the postman im getting empty response and when i checked in the console im getting **undefined**
Ive trained my bot and created model.nlp file also
i though the manager.process has some issue, but when checked via cmd its working as expected.
But when i tried via express server and route its returning undefined
how to fix this?

`const { NlpManager } = require("node-nlp");`
`const path = require('path');`
`const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../model.nlp');`  const manager = new NlpManager({ languages: ["en"], "modelFileName": "model.nlp"}); manager.load(filePath); console.log("Starting Chatbot ...1");`

`module.exports.createChatInterface = async (req, res) => {`
`console.log("Starting Chatbot ...");`
`let userMessage = req.body.message;`

```
    `let response = await manager.process("en", userMessage)`
    `.then((response) => {`
      `if (response && response.answer) {`
        `console.log(response.answer);`
        `res.status(200).json({ response: response.answer });`
      `} else {`
        `console.error("Chatbot response is undefined or empty");`
        `res.status(500).json({ error: "Chatbot response is undefined or empty" });`
      `}`
    `})`
    `.catch((err) => {`
      `console.error(err);`
      `res.status(500).json({ error: "Error in sending Message" });`
    `});`
```

`}`